# how to extract an attribute from parent tag in libxml + perl

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

I want to extract the attribute `lang` value from the parent tag `styling`. How do i obtain this?

I am using libxml.

I tried `getAttribute`, but it does not work on parent tag.

```
<styling lang="en-US">
  <style id="jason" tts:color="#00FF00" />
  <style id="violet" tts:color="#FF0000" />
  <style id="sarah" tts:color="#FFCC00" />
  <style id="eileen" tts:color="#3333FF" />
</styling>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think by "parent tag", you mean the root element. You probably want the `documentElement` method, a la:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.12;
use XML::LibXML 1.70;

my $doc = 'XML::LibXML'->new(recover => 1)->parse_fh(\*DATA);

say "GOT: ", $doc->documentElement->getAttribute('lang');

__DATA__
<styling lang="en-US">
  <style id="jason" tts:color="#00FF00" />
  <style id="violet" tts:color="#FF0000" />
  <style id="sarah" tts:color="#FFCC00" />
  <style id="eileen" tts:color="#3333FF" />
</styling>
```

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned `getAttribute` I assume you're using `XML::LibXML`. Here's a sample with two methods to get to the attribute value, one with XPath, another with `getAttribute` call:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = <<'EOF';
<styling lang="en-US" xmlns:tts="something">
  <style id="jason" tts:color="#00FF00" />
  <style id="violet" tts:color="#FF0000" />
  <style id="sarah" tts:color="#FFCC00" />
  <style id="eileen" tts:color="#3333FF" />
</styling>
EOF

print XML::LibXML->new->parse_string($xml)->findvalue('/styling/@lang'), "\n";
print XML::LibXML->new->parse_string($xml)->documentElement->getAttribute('lang'), "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 # use module
 use XML::Simple;
 use Data::Dumper;

 # create object
 $xml = new XML::Simple;

 # read XML file
 $data = $xml->XMLin("data.xml");

 $data->{styling}{lang};
```